# WebGL texImage2d: SECURITY_ERR using rasterizeHTML.js

Tags: webgl, user-agent, domexception, glteximage2d, security-policy

I'm using rasterizeHTML.js to create a canvas representing DOM elements of the webpage (such as a screenshot of the page), and then I'm passing it to texImage2d, in order to use this canvas as a texture. Althought it works fine in Firefox 21.0, in others browser (Chrome, Safari..) I get the following error:

```
SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through 
the security policy of the user agent.
```

Is there a way to bypass the security policy? I want to use it locally. I tried also to use a local webserver (MAMP) because I thought it could by due to the same origin policy but the error is the same... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The local web server is needed, but have you also made sure that all of the *images* you are loading are from that server, not from other origins? Use the browser's web inspector to make sure you are not loading any resources from other domains.